# Django mysql connection errors

Tags: python, mysql, django, wamp

Try to connect my django project with MySQL using wamp server i am facing error
"Django.db.utils.NotsupportedError"

I am tried older version of django
To solve this error, but it seems also
Same error.

Answer (score 0):

To connect Django to a MySQL database, you will need to install a MySQL database connector. The most common connector is mysql-connector-python, which you can install using pip:

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

Once the connector is installed, you will need to update your Django settings to use the connector and specify the connection parameters for your MySQL database. The settings will typically look like this:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
        'USER': 'myuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

You will need to replace the NAME, USER, PASSWORD, HOST, and PORT values with the appropriate values for your MySQL database.

Once you have configured your settings, you can run the migrate command to create the necessary database tables:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

This will create the tables in your MySQL database that are needed by Django. You should now be able to use your MySQL database with Django.